# Four square push api - application provider

Tags: api, foursquare

I am writing a four square application and after reading the push API, I realized that my users will have to authenticate and add a callback URL and all that good stuff listed below:

"To turn on real-time APIs for your consumer, access your consumer's details page by clicking on its name at https://foursquare.com/oauth. Then click the “Edit this Consumer” button in the upper right of the page.

To change your consumer's real-time API settings, pick the desired state from the drop-down menu on that page titled “Push API notifications.” Then click “Save this Consumer. ” You should now see your new notification settings reflected on the details page for your consumer.

If you have not activated a real-time API in the past, you will note that the Push URL field is blank on the details page. To actually receive real-time pushes from foursquare, you will need to edit your consumer again and add a HTTPS-compliant URL in this field."

Most of my users are not tech savvy to do this. How do I as an application provider automate or pre-poulate some fields in order to make it easy for them to register for the push api for my app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you enable the Push Api, you're doing it for all users who authorize your service. You will receive push notifications from all your authorized users... they don't have to explicitly authorize you to use the Push API